# Magento 2 shows 500 error after saving Transactional email logo in the Magento admin

Tags: magento2

I did some changes on my magento installation (inside admin panel) but for no logical reason my magento showed me HTTP ERROR 500 I am trying the commands php bin/magento setup:upgrade but everything going ok. Can anyone help me for what is that happend? 
I tried to reindex and to flush cache.
My installation is based on plesk and centos 7
Thank you

Suspicious Server Logs from Plesk:
1)Apache error

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught 
Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir 
"/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/var/cache/" is not writable in /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/var...')\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/var/www/vhosts...')\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(155): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Ca...\n'
```

Comment: Anything in your system.log or exception.log?

Comment: Also what did you save in the admin? This does count as a change so i have suggested an edit to your title

Comment: @dancarlyon No there is no such a file on my /var/log system

Comment: I would be looking to your server error logs for more information

Comment: @DanCarlyon I was trying to update the logo of transactional emails

Comment: @DanCarlyon Check my edit for server logs

Answer (score 1):

The error says it: your cache folder is not writable.

Make sure the folder `/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/var/cache/` is writable:

`sudo chmod a+w /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/var/cache/`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated question it seems your permissions are incorrect on your `var/cache` directory.

Make sure they are correct and have read-write permissions.

If you have ssh access you can do this with

```
chmod 777 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/var/cache/
```

Update:

The below command will set all directories to 770 and all files to 660

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

You can see more about this on the [magento devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html)

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed

Comment: Best bet would be to re-check the server error logs as there may be another directory that has incorrect permissions, eg generation.